# SQLiteOpenHelper crashes during first execution

Tags: android, sqlite

When I execute the app for the first time, my DbHelper creates the DB. But, when I try to open the database later (during the same app execution, in another activity), the database is created again because checkDatabase() returns false, and of course, this gives an exception because the tables exist. When I create the DB for the first time, I open it and close it, so I guess the problem is that the file is not refreshed (it is the only reason why second time checkDatabase() returns false).

It is important to say that this happens only during the first execution. After "Unfortunately,  has stopped" message, the database access works properly. Any idea???

Comment: Prefer the below link..
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: Without your code, this will become a guess game!

Comment: Post some code. For example, `checkDatabase()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to below code for when to create new database, check for existing DB

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DB_PATH;
private static String DB_NAME = "podcastDB.db";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + myContext.getPackageName() + "/databases/";

    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(myContext);
}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    // ---Check whether database is already created or not---
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            // ---If not created then copy the database---
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 * 
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        File f = new File(myPath);
        if (f.exists())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e("Podcast", "There was an error", e);
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    // --- Open the database---
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nirali! For any strange reason checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY); gave me exception when checking Database, but with your File version is perfect.

Comment: I would have thought there would be a solution to this problem that relied only on SQLite classes, i.e. without resorting to checking the filesystem.